# Best way to limit records between range in sql server for large database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a database with `250,000,000 records`, this records are necessary for daily operations(can't give much detail about this) and can't be moved to a historic database, there is a historic database even larger.

I have a form with several filters for the query, my problem is when the search query has no parameters and has to search the entire database. I don't want to retrieve the whole database at once. I want to do it in small batches of 1,000 every time the user clicks the next page in the results grid.

I'm currently doing somethin like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT col1,col2,col3,
ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY col1) as rownum
 FROM table1) x
 WHERE rownum BETWEEN 20000001 AND 20001000;
```

It works fast with a small table but if i want to search in ranges over 10,000 it gets slower and slower.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: First optimization - you don't have to actually pay the price of sorting. `ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) ` will have an execution plan that doesn't include sorting.

Comment: What is the index on col1?

Comment: Use fetch and offset instead of row number..

Comment: Just to add on the @ShakeerMirza's comment - https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2314819

Comment: Do records from this table get moved to the historic database in a Last-In First-Out kind of model? So one week the total range for col1 may be 250,000,000 - 500,000,000 (assuming it is an identity column), but the next it may be 265,000,000 - 515,000,000 and the records from 250,000,000 to 264,999,999 were move to the historic database?

Comment: @EricJ.Price yes the rows get moved periodically. the column 1 is an identity.

Comment: This should be handled by a proper UI control, and not on the back end. You are homegrowing paging and this is inefficient on all points.

Comment: [Pagination Done the Right Way](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way). It is written for Postgres, but the idea to use a proper index applies to any other RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try once using Offset and fetch Once so that we can fetch specfic range of     Records.
```

---

```
DECLARE @PageNo int = 1,
        @RowCountPerPage int = 1000
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  col3
WHERE rownum BETWEEN 20000001 AND 20001000
AND ORDER BY col1
OFFSET (@PageNo - 1) * @RowCountPerPage ROWS
FETCH NEXT @RowCountPerPage ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Read about [Problems with offset](http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset). Better idea is `keyset pagination`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that doing this query works better than the other options.

```
SELECT col1,col2 ,col3
FROM table
WHERE col1 BETWEEN 344079962 AND 344080962
```

0 seconds for every 10,000 records batch.

COL 1 is an identity.

I'm still looking for another posible solutions;

Thanks a lot.